# exclude dot with regular expression in R

Tags: r, string, list, vector, expression

i got a string vector from list.files() in R and want to exclude the strings with dot (.).
the codes are as follows

```
list.files(R.home(),pattern='[^\\.]') 
list.files(R.home(),pattern='[^.]')
```

they all don't work.
any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider using:

```
 list.files(pattern = "^[^.]+$")
```

This ensures there is no `.` from the beginning to the end of the string.

Comment: thank you very much. by the way, how to write regular expression to include specific string ( for example 'ab') and exclude specific string ( for example '.')?